# AWS Presigned URL valid for more than 7 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, pre-signed-url

Just wanted to know is there a way to use AWS S3 Presigned URL for more than 7 Days using V4 of Presigned URL.

Comment: What is your actual use-case? Most pre-signed URLs only need to be valid for a few minutes. Why do you need a link valid for a long duration?

Comment: We had an S3 object (audio) which needed to be downloaded and we were using it for that. We eventually solved it out by not using presigned url and instead creating links for direct download from S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Upto 7 days - Yes

> More than 7 days - NO

It is important to know the max expiration time differs with different ways which creates pre-signed URL

- Using s3 console - max 12 hours
- AWS explorer for Visual Studio - max 7 days
- AWS SDK - max 7 days
- AWS CLI - max 7 days

Docs for [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

> It becomes essential to understand that presigned URLs are used for limited time access, not long durations. In a broader scope, you are giving access to your bucket to some external identity why would you give access to some external identity that too for so long?

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately.

The current maximum expiration time for a presigned URL - which is a hard limit & cannot be increased - is 7 days from the time of creation.